# multiple instance if statement in xcode (iphone)

Tags: iphone, c, xcode, if-statement

what is the proper way to do If statement with two variable in Xcode for Iphone

currently I have

```
if (minute >0) && (second == 0) {
minute = minute - 1;
second = 59;
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The same was you would do it in any C/C++/Objective-C compiler, and most Algol derived languages, and extra set of parenthesis in order to turn to seperate boolean statements and an operator into a single compound statement:

```
if ((minute > 0) && (second == 0)) {
  minute = minute - 1;
  second = 59;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You'll need another set of parenthesis:

```
if ((minute >0) && (second == 0)) {
  minute = minute - 1;
  second = 59;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Or you could also write:

```
if (minute > 0 && second == 0)
```

Which is what you'll start doing eventually anyway, and I think (subjective) is easier to read.  Operator precedence insures this works...